# Are query times linear in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a table with 100 rows (with more or less constant size for each row), and a SELECT WHERE 1=1 query takes on average 0.004 seconds to complete, its ok to assume that with the same SELECT WHERE 1=1 but with 1M rows will take

```
totalTime = 1.000.000*0.004/100
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It seems `BENCHMARK` will be useful for you.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo Just theorical curiosity

Comment: In general, it's not safe to assume computer times are linear. A small query may be able to keep all data in memory, a big query may have to page, that will cause a knee in the performance curve.

Comment: @DomingoSL - no, it's not exactly linear. Remember, each execution has it's own overhead (network is one of the worst among them). And, of cause, do not forget that once query plan was built, next query will use it (from cache) and time will be reduced.

Comment: Start by asking, if I run the same query repeatedly, does it always take 0.004 seconds to complete, no obviously not. Then consider the effects of parallelism. As more results are required there is more opportunity for parallel processing.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not ok to assume that. There are many variables ranging from your hardware to your database structure to the version of MySQL you use that can all affect how the query time will scale with more records.